# How to modify my legends when arranging several plots together to don't collapse the plots with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 16 plots that I want to arrange together for illustration purposes. Below I show one graph as an example.

[image]

The code for creating each plot is next:

```
P1<- ggplot(Fish_acc_C.D.Mean_bottom_invierno_P16, aes(C.D.Mean_bottom,meanAcc)) +
  geom_point(aes(C.D.Mean_bottom,meanAcc, color = C.I.Mean_bottom),show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("green","black")) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = "Activity"),fill = "lightblue",color="red", alpha = 0.99) +
  ggtitle("Activity ~ Curr Direct Mean bottom WINTER (Hourly data)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10,hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(C.D.Mean_bottom, C.I.Mean_bottom * max(range(Fish_acc_C.D.Mean_bottom_invierno_P16$C.I.Mean_bottom)), linetype = "C.I.M.B"), se=FALSE, colour = "blue",show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . /max(range(Fish_acc_C.D.Mean_bottom_invierno_P16$C.I.Mean_bottom)), name = "C.I.Mean bottom")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,1),guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c("red", "blue")))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1.25))  +
  theme(legend.justification = c(1,1),
        legend.position = c(1,1))
```

My problem is that when I use `grid.arrange()` to group them all together, the legends of each plot increase their size with regard to their size in the individual ones. Here an example:

[image]

Here I show the code for creating the grid_arrange:

```
grid.arrange(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10,P11,P12,P13,P14,P15,P16,ncol=4)
```

Does anyone know how to reduce the size of the legends in the `grid_arranged` graph in order to see the lines? I thought that maybe I could place the legends in the upper-middle position of the graph, delete the word "linetype" from the legend and display the `linetypes` in one line (side by side instead of up and down). However I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone have any recommendation?

Comment: If they all the same, maybe you can extract the legend using `get_legend()` from `cowplot` package and then `grid.arrange()` plot without legend and have legend on the side.

Comment: Thanks @SinhNguyen. I think that if I show the legend on the side, it will take up space for the plots, and since I'm plotting 16 graphs, space is essential. I think a good option might be to move the legends to the upper-middle zone of the plot, removing the word "linetype" and placing the linetypes side by side in one row. However, I don't know how to do it. I have just updated my post showing the code I used to create the plots.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the `ggarrange` function from the `ggpubr` package.
It allows you to group your plots as you need and have a common legend for all of them, for which you can specify the position.

e.g.

```
library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(g1, g2, ncol = 2, common.legend = T, legend = 'bottom')

# or
ggarrange(plotlist = my_list, ncol = 2, common.legend = T, legend = 'bottom')
```

Comment: Thanks @Romain. Can I place the legend in the upper-middle part of the graph? I indicated `top` and the function place the legend in the top-right part. In any case, your solution is fine, so thanks :)

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to put the common legend *inside* the plots with `ggpubr`, sorry. I looked a bit into it and maybe you can do something with the [`annotate_figure()`](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/annotate_figure.html) function of the package, by having the legend as a grob and adding it on top (no idea how to implement it though).

Answer (score 0):

@Dekike then you can extract the legend and put the legend on top/bottom of the main plot.

Here are my psude code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

P1 <- ggplot() + ... + guides(lineType=guide_legend(ncol=2))
legend_extracted <- get_legend(P1)

P1 <- P1 + theme(legend.position="none")
P2 <- ggplot() + ... + theme(legend.position="none")
...
P16 <- ggplot() + ... + theme(legend.position="none")

main_plot <- grid.arrange(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10,P11,P12,P13,P14,P15,P16,ncol=4)
main_plot_wLegend <- grid.arrange(legend_extracted, main_plot, ncol=1, nrow=2)
```

Please try and feedback on this!